# Conflicting Auto Completes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have an Ajax auto complete textbox in my .NET 4.0 asp.net page via a web service, but the browser auto complete dropdownlist feature shows up on top of my .net auto complete dropdownlist.

Is there a way to make sure the browsers auto complete feature does not popup on this textbox? Almost like an override to make sure the browser doesn't try to help out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Mozila, Chrome and Safari have implemented:

`<input type="text"... autocomplete="OFF"/>`

so if you are using HTML use the autocomplete="OFF"

The same applies for ASP.NET TextBoxes.

`<asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" autocomplete="OFF"/>`

I am not sure what happens on IE, but i am pretty sure it also respects this attribute.